# Compare two arrays and filter with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to filter an array and compare it with another array with a condition.

```
const array1 = [
    {id: 'q1', type: 'single'},
    {id: 'q2', type: 'multiple'},
    {id: 'q3', type: 'single'},
    {id: 'q4', type: 'single'}
];

const array2 = [
   {newId: 'q1', status: 'submitted'},
   {newId: 'q2', status: 'drafted'},
   {newId: 'q2', status: 'submitted'},
   {newId: 'q2', status: 'submitted'},
   {newId: 'q4', status: 'drafted'}
];
const resultArray = [
   {id: 'q2', type: 'multiple'}, 
   {id: 'q3', type: 'single'}
];
```

I have tried with the map function but I get the wrong result. This is my code:

```
let resultArray = [];
map(array1, el => {
    if(el.type==='single'){
        map(array2, elm => {
            if(el.id!==elm.newId){
                newData.push(el);
            }
        })
    }else{
        newData.push(el);
    }
});
newData = uniqBy(newData, 'id');
```

array1 has the type single/multiple, if the type is single, then array2 has that object one time or if the type is multiple it can be multiple times in array2.

Comment: What is the compare condition?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: if the  el. type === 'single'  then i have to compare el.id !== elm.newId

Comment: Expected Output is
const resultArray = [
   {id: 'q2', type: 'multiple'}, 
   {id: 'q3', type: 'single'}
];

Comment: How is `q3` filtered in and `q1` and `q4` filtered out?

Comment: what is the logic of filtration behind this?

Comment: @RaviKumarGopalakrishnan You said `if the type is single array2 have that object one time`, so where did `q3` occur 1 time in array2 ?

Comment: Please add what will the output condition? If you are trying to find only multiple occurrence of a key, then expected output will be  [ {id: 'q2', type: 'multiple'}], if you are trying to find out occurrence of all the key, then output shall be  [ {id:'q1', type:'single'},{id: 'q2', type: 'multiple'}, {id: 'q3', type: 'single'},{id:'q4', type:'single'}];
What result are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: what about if you have multiple, in `array1` a single entry and in `array2` another one, is this sufficient?

Comment: Thank you Guys ...

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

- Convert a map for array2 where key is id and value is its occurrence
- Filter array1 based on following rules

  - If type is multiple, then it should exist in map with occurrence more than once
  - Else if type is single, then it should not exist in map at all.

```js
const array1=[{id:'q1',type:'single'},{id:'q2',type:'multiple'},{id:'q3',type:'single'},{id:'q4',type:'single'}];
const array2=[{newId:'q1',status:'submitted'},{newId:'q2',status:'drafted'},{newId:'q2',status:'submitted'},{newId:'q2',status:'submitted'},{newId:'q4',type:'drafted'}];

let a2Map = array2.reduce((a,c) => {
  a[c.newId] = a[c.newId] || 0;
  a[c.newId]++;
  return a;
}, {});

let result = array1.filter(v => v.type === 'multiple' ? a2Map[v.id] > 1 : !a2Map.hasOwnProperty(v.id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @RaviKumarGopalakrishnan - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` and count all items with the same `newId` from `array2`. Then filter `Array2` with the conditions for single or multiple values.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ id: 'q1', type: 'single' }, { id: 'q2', type: 'multiple' }, { id: 'q3', type: 'single' }, { id: 'q4', type: 'single' }],
    array2 = [{ newId: 'q1', status: 'submitted' }, { newId: 'q2', status: 'drafted' }, { newId: 'q2', status: 'submitted' }, { newId: 'q2', status: 'submitted' }, { newId: 'q4', type: 'drafted' }],
    map = array2.reduce((m, { newId }) => m.set(newId, (m.get(newId) || 0) + 1), new Map),
    result = array1.filter(({ id, type }) =>
        type === 'single' && !map.get(id) || // not in map, count:  0
        type === 'multiple' && map.get(id)   // in map,     count: >0    
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```